# Почему php script отправки сообщения в telegram срабатывает несколько раз?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, sendmessage

Есть бот и php файл.
Я с telegram отправляю start.
В php скрипте (`$string_input = file_get_contents('php://input');`) есть такая последовательность:

```
if ($text=="start"){
     sendMessage(1);
     first($connect);
     sendMessage(2);
     second($connect);
     sendMessage(3);
     third($connect);
     sendMessage(4);
 }
```

или даже при таком раскладе:

```
if ($text=="start"){
         sendMessage(1);
         sleep(30);
         sendMessage(2);
         sleep(30);
         sendMessage(3);
         sleep(30);
         sendMessage(4);
     }
```

Если вместо 30 сек поставить 5 сек, то все норм работает.

И это последовательность работает неправильно. В телеграм сообщения отправляются:

```
       ~ start  

1
2
3
4
1
3
2
4
1
3  
2
1  
4
. . .
```

Каждая функция обрабатывается примерно по минуту. Если комментировать эти функции, то все хорошо работает. Поискал в интернете, думаю проблема в ответе, либо 200 или ok, но не помогло, или я не смог.

Помогите найти решение, а то уже несколько дней не могу понять...

Comment: 200 это и есть Ок. Больше кода выложите там где функции

Comment: дело не в коде, а в ожидании... вместо функции я использовал sleep... тот же результат

Comment: Дело в коде. Просто так не бывает никаких нарушений. `sleep()` не рекомендую использовать

Comment: В том то и дело, что ошибка не в коде, sleep() я использовал для проверки... дело в том что во время долгого ожидании script выполняется несколько раз